# HTML5 canvas inspector?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, inspector

Is there any ability to inspect the objects rendered on a HTML5 canvas like we can do in Silverlight with Silverlight Spy ?

If I use Chrome elements inspector I can inspect only DOM.

Comment: JavaScript is not HTML. I updated your question.

Comment: Google Chrome's Profile tab under Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) might do the trick. I've never tried with canvas though.

Comment: @minitech: The profiles tab lets you look at JavaScript CPU and heap usage; it doesn't really have anything to do with what's rendered on-screen.

Comment: @josh3736: Sorry, I thought the OP meant canvas profiling, never mind :P

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**EDIT:**
this answer doesn't work on new chrome versions see:
[chrome canvas inspector 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439201/chrome-canvas-inspector-2015)

In Chrome Canary:

1. in your browser, enter this url `chrome://flags/`
2. enable *Enable Developer Tools experiments*
3. relaunch Chrome
4. in the developer tools, click the `gear` to bring up developer preferences
5. select *experiments* from the menu
6. select *Canvas Inspections*
7. close devtools, refresh the page, reopen devtools

---

The full guide on the canvas profiler:
  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/

Animated gif showing it in action:
https://twitter.com/umaar/status/480705624448045057

Comment: is there a reason why this would miracoluously disappear? I had it working in both canary and vanilla, one day poof. Dev tools experiments still enabled, no profiler, no canvas inspections?

Comment: @jedierikb can you please let me know what is 'gear' and where and how I can find it. When open developer tools it opens up elements inspect window. where and what is 'gear'?

Comment: @Alex - in the latest version of Canary this means `Settings` the 3 vertical dots in top right corner (or use F1).

Comment: as @pailhead pointed out this doesn't seem to be available in the latest versions - I cannot see this in `49.0.2621.0 canary (64-bit)`. I think Firefox Canvas debugger might work kind-of-okay... but it will be nice to get this back

Comment: I'm not able to find the "Enable Developer Tools experiments" option in latest version of chrome, maybe it's name is changed, please help me find the alternate option to use canvas inspect.

Comment: As of 4/26/21, Canvas Inspections is no longer an option under Experiments.

Comment: So they just removed it without any notification?

Answer (score 28):

Canvas' content is not part of the DOM, so there is no way you could inspect it's content. As you have correctly pointed, inspectors can inspect DOM only, hence canvas is out of it's scope. You can check the contents of the canvas in the console of your devtools though with

```
yourcanvas.toDataURL();
```

and check the output dataURL in the neighbouring tab.

Comment: Canvas is bitmap: it's content is only what you see on the screen

Comment: Not quite sure what the last comment was in aid of, thanks @spliter - that's great for debugging!

Comment: This might not be what the OP wanted but it's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: This have to be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 12):

There are no objects rendered on an HTML5 Canvas. There are only pixels. When you draw a shape the canvas waves its wand, pixels appear, and then it forgets that anything even happened.

As many have done, you can keep track of what you draw on a Canvas in order to have persistent objects for redrawing. I've written [A Gentle Introduction to Making HTML5 Canvas Interactive](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305200544/http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful), and no doubt if you search you'll find other tutorials.

As you build up your system of persistent objects you'll almost certainly want to include a lot of debug code that outputs easy to understand lists of objects and their coordinates. A lot of people choose to do this with `console.log` statements that will output whatever strings you want to the developer console (part of the F12 developer tools in most modern browsers).

But that's it. What you build is what you get to use to inspect things.

Comment: Correct.. there no browsers to support canvas inspection yet.. only one way to use right framework like [Kohana](http://alertdevelop.ru/projects/profilertoolbar)

Answer (score 2):

Treat canvas as ms paint. There are no objects, there are only pixels and methods to put them on screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to inspect the canvas content *at the moment*, But in case of WebGL you can use " [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.com/WebGL-Inspector/) " extension for Google Chrome, so I think *it is possible* to make similar extension for Canvas too. but it doesn't work like common DOM inspectors.

Here is the WebGL Inspector features:

- Extension for injecting into pages
- Embed in an existing application with a single script include
- Capture entire GL frames
- Annotated call log with stepping/resource navigation and redundant call warnings
- Pixel history - see all draw calls that contributed to a pixel + blending information
- GL state display
- Resource browsers for textures, buffers, and programs

Let's hope I'm not off-road, but there is no Bitmap or Vector Canvas **inspector** at the moment.

Comment: Hi @sysop, I am not able to find this in chrome settings, not sure if google has changed it. pl. let me know