# how to inspect html of Google sheets in firefox

Tags: html, inspect

I am trying to inspect html of Google drive's Sheets. They have override the right click. How can I inspect the html elements?

I am using firefox

Comment: You can press F12 to access the developer console. Firefox, you can find the hotkey [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts)

Comment: @Codelord I have. But it seems very difficult to inspect Google sheets html.

Comment: have you tried it? try it and if possible tell me the html of one cell in the sheet. Is it input field?

Comment: I am unable to inspect a cell as well. @Alex did you get the answer to this question?

Comment: @Rads press Ctrl+F12

Comment: @Alex I am able to inspect, but the issue is google is using canvas to display all the cell values so when I inspect I cannot get access to the cell values.

Comment: @Rads I have updated my answer. Check it out

Comment: @Rads I have updated again my answer. check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To inspect I had to use key: Ctrl+F12.

**Update** To Inspect elements inside canvas, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14466889/4810628

**Update** You can also try CSSViewer extension of Google Chrome to inspect elements and associated CSS

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for an answer to such an old question..

The unwritten standard pertains to holding the SHIFT key whilst you right click; which reverts the action to the default context menu.

I'm also aware of a few people that, rather than using the shift key method, they make it so you have to right click twice (once for custom menu, second time for default menu).

EDIT (June 2019):
It's not just SHIFT key I've seen people using -- it can be CTRL or ALT.
On reflection - ALT is probably the best for implementation -- as SHIFT & CTRL can affect highlighted text (not preferable in some circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy no plugin method. Since Google has overridden contextMenu event of the canvas we just need to disable it temporarily and then you can inspect like a normal web page.

1. In the Inspector Window find the HTML tag for canvas which is pretty easy as it is a big container.
2. Click on the event associated with it and disable the contextmenu event.

Screenshots:

[image: disabling contextmenu event]

After event is disabled

[image: after event is disabled]