# How to inspect a <canvas> in Safari?

Tags: safari, html5-canvas, web-inspector

I have a need to inspect what is being drawn in a `<canvas>`, as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143209/html5-canvas-inspector). And I know how to use the [Chrome dev tools canvas inspector](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/), and the [Firefox Canvas Debugger](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/03/introducing-the-canvas-debugger-in-firefox-developer-tools/).

Are there any similar tools **for the Safari web browser**?

For the sake of clarity, let's assume desktop Safari v9.1.1 running in OSX 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this with [WebKit's Canvas debugging tools](https://webkit.org/blog/8452/canvas-debugging/):

[image: The Canvas debugging tab in WebKit devtools]

Note that this tool is now available under the Graphics tab in newer versions of WebKit.

[image: Graphics tab in newer versions of WebKit]